# Why is it not allowed to assign a subtype to parameters in an AroundInvoke interceptor in Quarkus?

Tags: java, quarkus

Imagine a method with a single parameter of type `Object`, annotated with an interceptor annotation:

```
@Foo
public void test(Object obj) { ... }
```

In the interceptor's `aroundInvoke` method, I try to set a string as the parameter:

```
@Foo @Interceptor
public class FooInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object testInterception(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        Object[] params = new Object[] {"test"};
        ctx.setParameters(params);
        return ctx.proceed();
    }

}
```

I end up with an IllegalArgumentException: "The parameter type [class java.lang.String] does not match the type for the target method [class java.lang.Object]".

The reason is that the method `validateParameters` in `AbstractInvocationContext` compares the target type and the actual type using `equals` instead of `isAssignableFrom`. I could not find anything in the CDI or the interceptor specification that forbids assigning an instance of a subtype.

Is this not supposed to work, or is it simply a bug?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, but I'm not an expert. I'd suggest to file a bug in the Quarkus issue tracker, so that the right people can see it (and fix it if needed).